# ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: oracle10g

```
Name               Null     Type           
------------------ -------- -------------- 
RESOURCE_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
RESOURCE_FIRST_NM  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)   
RESOURCE_MIDDLE_NM          VARCHAR2(30)   
RESOURCE_LAST_NM   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)   
RESOURCE_TYPE_CD   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)   
EMPLOYEE_ID                 VARCHAR2(20)   
EMPLOYEE_TYPE_CD            VARCHAR2(10)   
FUNCTIONAL_LEAD_CD          VARCHAR2(10)   
PHONE_1                     VARCHAR2(15)   
PHONE_2                     VARCHAR2(15)   
FAX_NR                      VARCHAR2(15)   
EMAIL_DE                    VARCHAR2(50)   
RESOURCE_STATUS_CD NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)   
HIRING_DT          NOT NULL DATE           
LEAVE_START_DT              DATE           
LEAVE_END_DT                DATE           
TERMINATED_DT               DATE           
ADDRESS1                    VARCHAR2(50)   
ADDRESS2                    VARCHAR2(50)   
CITY                        VARCHAR2(15)   
STATE                       VARCHAR2(15) 


int i=statement.executeUpdate("
     insert into RAS_T_RESOURCES(
         RESOURCE_ID, 
         RESOURCE_FIRST_NM, 
         RESOURCE_MIDDLE_NM, 
         RESOURCE_LAST_NM, 
         RESOURCE_TYPE_CD, 
         EMPLOYEE_ID, 
         FUNCTIONAL_LEAD_CD, 
         ADDRESS1, 
         ADDRESS2, 
         PHONE_1, 
         PHONE_2, 
         FAX_NR, 
         EMAIL_DE, 
         RESOURCE_STATUS_CD, 
         HIRING_DT, 
         LEAVE_START_DT, 
         LEAVE_END_DT, 
         TERMINATED_DT,
         CITY,
         STATE)
    values(
         2,  
         '"+strFirstname+"', 
         '"+strMiddlename+"', 
         '"+strLastname+"', 
         '"+strResourceType+"', 
         '"+strEmpId+"', 
         '"+strHiringMngr+"', 
         '"+strAddress1+"', 
         '"+strAddress2+"',
         '"+strPhone1+"', 
         '"+strPhone2+"', 
         '"+strFax+"', 
         '"+strEMail+"', 
         '"+strstatus+"', 
         "+strHiringDate+", 
         "+strStartDate+", 
         "+strEndDate+", 
         "+strTerminatedDate+", 
         '"+strCity+"', 
         '"+strState+"');");
```

Can any one help?  What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the problem is that you're not using bind variables and that you're getting an error related to concatenating a string.  If there are commas in the data, for example, that will cause problems.  Any of the Oracle `DATE` columns will generate issues if the Java string happens not to match the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

For performance, usability, and security reasons, I'd strongly suggest using bind variables instead.

Comment: I have used ------------String strDate=request.getParameter("txtHiringDate");
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
           
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

Comment: Probably, the issue comes from date-string inconsistency. Why don't you try putting the insert statement into a variable before executing, then debug the variable? So, you can see the error the statement contains.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking purely as a compiler, expressions like this:

```
     '"+strFirstname+"'
```

would be interpreted as literal strings. (No variable substitution would take place, if that's what you're thinking.)

This bit here is probably the problem:

```
     "+strHiringDate+", 
     "+strStartDate+", 
     "+strEndDate+", 
     "+strTerminatedDate+",
```

These would be parsed by Oracle as identifiers, not strings - because you've omitted the single quotes ('), and Oracle identifiers are optionally delimited by double quotes (").

Comment: Date strHiringDate  = null; 
           Date strStartDate  =  null;
           Date strEndDate  =  null;
           Date strTerminatedDate  =  null;

Comment: Hi user1241779, you're not getting my point. Your query *will not use* those variables, because your query is looking for identifiers that are, literally: `+strHiringDate+`, *including* the `+` characters, because you have surrounded them with double-quotes.